# почему в логах отображает имя пк со знаком $

Tags: windows, логирование

почему в логах отображает имя пк со знаком $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, потому что в логах пишется учётная запись компьютера, имя которой в домене Active Directory формируется как имя компьютера со знаком $.

Comment: Просто на форуме http://isaserver.ru/forums/t/8275.aspx прочитал что это софт лезет в инет а не юзер, но засомневался. Спасибо за ответ